# Dropbox Application; Is it possible to check when a folder or a file is created or modified?

Tags: dropbox

Is it possible to check when a folder or a file is created or modified in my Dropbox Application's folder?

Comment: All right, I found the answer.. Developers who want to get information of changes user did in application can use dropbox Delta API or REST API Delta URL.. https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#delta

Comment: You can put that as an Answer :)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I found the answer.. Developers who want to get information of changes user did in application can use dropbox Delta API or REST API Delta URL..

dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#delta

"https://api.dropbox.com/1/delta" URL in REST API returns last changes as a Json Object.