# event new file created in dropbox api

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I am writting a program that uses DROPBOX API in java downloaded from its page: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core
In my program, I want to be notified when a new file is created in a folder. I found a clue from this link [Dropbox Application; Is it possible to check when a folder or a file is created or modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741899/dropbox-application-is-it-possible-to-check-when-a-folder-or-a-file-is-created). However, the solution is not clear. Can anyone help me out with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in that other thread is correct. You want to call delta. Here's the Java-specific documentation for it: http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.7.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxClient.html#getDelta(java.lang.String).

Comment: I got delta but I donnot know how can I know when a new file is created from delta's infor, I use System.out.println to see the information of  delta, but it seems that it tells me all information of all files, but cannot decide which file is new or old. Can you give me a specific solution.

Comment: Your code just needs to remember the files it's already seen. A file is new if you see it in a delta and haven't seen it before.

Comment: If you want more help, please share the code you've written so far.